# Can't read binary matrix from a file in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So, I have to do these two functions, one that saves a binary matrix on a .bin file and one that reads that same file and returns the `numpy.array`.

My problem is that when I try to .vstack both line and final image (I basically want to save a Black and White image) I get this message error:

> 'ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly'

which makes sense because after the I read the second line binaryLine and final image have different length, for some reason I can't understand.

```py
def save_binary_matrix(img, fileName):
    file = open(fileName, "w+")
    heigth, width = img.shape
    image = convert_BW_to_0_1(img) # converts from 0 and 255 to 0 and 1
    for y in range(heigth):
        for x in range(0, width, 8):
            bits = image[y][x:x+8]# gets every 8 bits
            s = ''
            # converts bits to a string
            for i in range(len(bits)):
                s = s + str(bits[i])
            file.write(str(int(s,2)))# saves the string as a integer
        file.write("\n")# line change
    file.close()

def read_binary_matrix(fileName):
    file = open(fileName, "r")
    #saves first line of the file
    finalImage = np.array([])
    line = file.readline()
    for l in range(len(line)):
        if line[l] != '\n':
            finalImage = np.append(finalImage, np.array([int(x) for x in list('{0:08b}'.format(int(line[l])))]))
    #reads and saves other lines
    for line in file:
        binaryLine = np.array([])
        for l in range(len(line)):
            if line[l] != '\n':
                #read and saves line as binary value
                binaryLine = np.append(binaryLine, np.array([int(x) for x in list('{0:08b}'.format(int(line[l])))]))
            finalImage = np.vstack((finalImage, binaryLine))
    return finalImage
```

Comment: Why not just use `numpy.save()` and `numpy.load()`? And no, your files are not binary, they are text files with binary representations of integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Twice you create a `np.array([])`.  Pay attention to its shape:

```
In [140]: x = np.array([])                                                      
In [141]: x.shape                                                               
Out[141]: (0,)
```

It does work in `np.append` - that's because without axis parameter, `append` is just `concatenate((x, y), axis=0)`, e.g. adding a (0,) shape and a (3,) shape to create a (3,) shape:

```
In [142]: np.append(x, np.arange(3))                                            
Out[142]: array([0., 1., 2.])
```

But `vstack` doesn't work.  It makes its inputs into 2d arrays, and joins them on the first axis:

```
In [143]: np.vstack((x, np.arange(3)))                                          
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

So we are joining (0,) and (3,) on a new first axis, e.g. (1,0) and (1,3) on first axis.  The 0 and 3 don't match, hence the error.

`vstack` works when joining a (3,) with a (3,) and a (1,3), and a (4,3).  Note the common 'last' dimension.

The underlying problem is that you are trying to emulate the list append, without fully understanding dimensions, or what `concatenate` does.  It makes a whole new array each time.  `np.append` is not a clone of `list.append`!.

What you should be doing is starting with a `[]` list (or two), append new values to that, making a list of lists.  Then `np.array(alist)` to turn that into an array (provided, of course that all sublists match in size).

I haven't paid attention to your write, or how you read the lines, so can't say whether that makes sense or not.